# fullpage carousel with hammer.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hammer.js

I'm trying to adapt the example at https://rawgit.com/hammerjs/hammer.js/master/tests/manual/nested.html to allow for fullpage panning, however I am not sure how to account for browser resizing and dynamically adding/removing panes.

I've tried resetting the carousel on resize as well as on changes to the DOM.
However, in both cases, if I reinitialize the carousel, it gets reset back to index 0. Any suggestions?

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  outer = new HammerCarousel(document.querySelector(".panes.wrapper"),      Hammer.DIRECTION_HORIZONTAL);
});
```

I have a fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/afroz/0jq5ynq8/1/

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by setting an environment variable to the current index and then modifying the carousel function to read that instead of using the default index of 0.

I've modified the fiddle with the fixes.